# Why am i NOT getting null pointer exception in this case while adding null to a list and sorting it

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Whenever i change the condition to i==2 or i==3 i always get NPE but not in case of 5 why?
I have no more details to add the question is self explanatory i guess

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        List<X> arr=new ArrayList<X>();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        arr.add(new X(i));
        if(i==5){
            arr.add(null);
        }
        }

        Collections.sort(arr);
        for(X x:arr){
            System.out.println(x.i);
        }
    }

}

class X implements Comparable{
    public int i;
    public X(int i2) {
        i=i2;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return new Random().nextInt(10)-5;
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I have no more details to add the question is self explanatory i guess"* What was the constructive purpose of that statement?

Comment: C'mon. You loop runs only when `i < 5`.  So `i = 5` cannot possibly happen.

Comment: **Debugger** - *noun* (1) A software tool that allows inspecting compiled programs while running with features like statement-by-statement execution of code, inspecting variables, setting breakpoints, and other means of understanding program flow and behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That loop only goes to 4 for `i`, so you don't end up inserting anything when you change the conditon to `i == 5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(i==5){
    arr.add(null);
}
```

Is never executed, since the loop is from 0 to 4. (`for(int i=0;i<5;i++)`).

BTW, adding the null into the list doesn't cause the NullPointerException by itself.
What causes the execption is trying to call a method of a null instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess you are right. I thought the sort wouldn't be a problem because compareTo doesn't access the object at all, but calling compareTo on the null instance would cause the NullPointerException.

Comment: The NPE would occur while sorting when compareTo is called on null object

Answer (score 0):

It's because your for loop never actually goes up to 5:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
```

This will only actually cycle through the values 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 due to your use of the strict inequality. If you want to include 5 you should use <= instead of <.

I would suggest that you familiarise yourself with breakpoints, as using them would be a very quick way to spot that you were never actually adding the null when your code executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop exits before `i == 5`. Look at your for loop:

```
for( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

This means that, before iterating the loop, it checks to see if the condition `i < 5` is true. If so, the loop runs. Afterward, i is incremented by 1, and the check is made again. When i is equal to 5, the check fails, as 5 is not less than 5.  Therefore, the line inside the if statement never runs, and a Null Pointer Exception is avoided.